# An English copy of One Hundred Authors Against Einstein?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, reference-request, relativity-theory

I've been trying to find the famous article, "One hundred authors against Einstein" (100 Autoren gegen Einstein), of various objections to special relativity, which is quite often referenced, but finding a copy proved to be quite hard (there is one available [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3226005375)), and I can't seem to find it in English at all.

Was this text ever translated, and where might I be able to find a copy of it?

Comment: Why not learn German?

Comment: I have strong doubts that anyone cared to translate this to any language.

Comment: This goes over the main arguments of the contributors to _100 Autoren_: https://books.google.com/books?id=mCOtbqBPNhQC&pg=PA248

Comment: On this site https://archive.org/details/HundertAutorenGegenEinstein is a text pdf.
Copy the text and put it through a translator :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a link to [online version in German](http://bourabai.kz/articles/100/page01.htm). As for the English translation, according to Milena Wazeck's [Einstein's Opponents: The Public Controversy about the Theory of Relativity](https://books.google.com/books?id=w-RRAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=100+authors+against+Einstein+english+translation&source=bl&ots=w8c-zaZ5f1&sig=dW4GljRXr-8ps21tLWUd8ySS85M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAgZWj4OvLAhUK5GMKHYA3C7gQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=100%20authors%20against%20Einstein%20english%20translation&f=false) "*nothing ever came of an English language version of 100 Autoren - no such book exists*". This is despite the fact that Reuterdahl (one of the contributors) and Ruckhaber (one of the German edition editors) wanted to publish one in the US already back in 1931. But they had great difficulty finding a publisher because of the Great Depression and lack of scientific backers. According to Reuterdahl it was because scientists were afraid "*of loosing scientific caste, and perhaps their position*". Einstein offered a different explanation in his response to 100 Autoren ([source](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3485/232)):

> If I were wrong, then one [author] would have been enough!

Comment: This seems to be a slightly higher quality scan: http://www.literature.at/viewer.alo?viewmode=overview&objid=17088&page=

Comment: Interestingly, Sagnac is referenced in it.

Comment: An OCRed version: https://archive.org/details/HundertAutorenGegenEinstein

Answer (score 1):

There is now an English version available : https://www.amazon.fr/One-Hundred-Authors-Against-Einstein/dp/B09PHH7KC8